# google-analytics installed using pipenv can't find modules

Tags: python, google-analytics, pipenv

I'm trying to use google-analytics in a pipenv environment. I'm having problems immediately after installation. After running `pipenv shell`, I ran `pipenv install google-api-python-client googleanalytics`. Upon running `import googleanalytics as ga` I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/.../lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleanalytics/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import utils, account, columns, errors, oauth, query
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

In `.../site-packages/googleanalytics` I can see the modules (utils, account, etc.). Is it possible there might be some conflict with other modules? I'm not very familiar with how pipenv works so I'm not sure what to do. Is it possible this is related to Python 3.10?